# List of queries on Data Explorer for assisting in maintenance effort

Tags: discussion

This meta question contains a list of Data Explorer queries to identify areas of the site that requires attention.

Please post one query per answer, plus some comments and recommended actions.

When you add an answer, please also update the question with the title of your query.

- [**Posts in danger of automatic deletion**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/list-of-queries-on-data-explorer-for-assisting-in-maintenance-effort#2328)

Comment: I think it might be worth just updating this one instead: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/883/

Comment: @senshin: That one is better. It is possible to make it displays on the right side on the home page of meta - like the list of frequently asked question on SO?

Comment: As far as I know, no, that isn't possible. Meta.SO and Meta.SE seem to be special-cased in to list questions tagged with [meta-tag:faq] in the right-hand sidebar. This does not seem to be an option for other sites.

Comment: @senshin: Can you make a feature-request for it on Meta.SE? With so many stuffs on meta, I think it would be useful.

Comment: Looks like there is one already - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240186/

Answer (score 1):

### [Posts in danger of automatic deletion](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/303966/posts-in-danger-of-automatic-deletion)

Review the question and see whether the question is worth keeping on our site.

If you think the question is good, Upvote the question to minimal threshold (score +1 for question with owner, score +2 for question without owner). If the question has already passed the threshold, there is no need to force yourself to upvote it if you find it mediocre.

**Do not blindly upvote/downvote everything in the list**